# Natural way to format strings with c++

Tags: c++, string

With C, I know that one usually `sprintf` to format strings.

**But what is the natural way to format a `std::string` with C++?**

```
int i = 2;
std::string s = std::string("hello letter ") + ('A' + i) + std::string(" bye bye")
```

Expected output: a `std::string` containing "hello letter C bye bye"

I get a rather cryptic error:

> error C2784: 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'int'

When using `to_string('A' + i)`, there is no error, but it prints "67" instead of "C".

---

*Note: `_UNICODE` is defined (platform: win32 / VC++), can I still use `std::string` sometimes in my code, or is it **mandatory**
 that everything is `std::wstring` everywhere?*

Comment: `'A'` is an _integer_ (!!), but `"A"` is a `std::string` (or can be one, depending on context).

Comment: Cast to `char` first?

Comment: `'A' + i` is of type `int`, you may use `char('A' + i)`.

Comment: @ForceBru: `'A'` is a `char,` it is `'A' + i` which is of type `int`. (and `"A"` is of type `const char[2]`).

Comment: @ForceBru -- `'A'` has type `char` in C++. In C it's `int`.

Comment: @Charles or Jarod42 it works, do you want to post an answer?

Comment: "With C, I know that one usually `sprintf` to format strings." - and C++ doesn't really have anything better builtin; typically I wrap it into a C++-friendly wrapper that handles memory allocation on its own and returns an `std::string` and I'm happy with it.

Comment: [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) not working for some reason?

Comment: @genpfault I was going to suggest the same thing, but then realized he would run into the same problem. `('A' + i)` will be formatted as a number, not character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast to char so that [`std::string::operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) works.

```
int i = 2;
std::string s = std::string("hello letter ") + char('A' + i) + std::string(" bye bye");
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles! Even `std::string s = std::string("hello letter ") + char('A' + i) + " bye bye";` works. But how to explain that `std::string s = "hello letter " + char('A' + i) + " bye bye";` doesn't work? ("cannot add two pointers")

Comment: There is no defined `+` for a `char*` and a `char`, so the first two operands can't be added, and therefore neither can the last part be added to the result of the first two... The first works because you can add a `char` to a `std::string` and then the result of that (`std::string`) to a `char*`.

Comment: Actually, you can add a `char*` and a `char`. It is basic pointer arithmetic (`char` is just a small integer type), and results in another pointer, offset from the first by whatever the integral value of your `char` is. The problem is the second `+`, which attempts to add the result of the first one (a `char*`) with another `char*`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley My mistake. But that `char*` and `char` doesn't add in the way you want here. That's another thing.

Answer (score 4):

Given that `i` is an `int`, the type of `'A' + i` is also `int` (see integer promotion rules). `std::string` does not have an `operator+` overload for `int`. Side note: overload resolution, implicit conversions and template deduction are very useful for reuse of terse, generic code but have a tendency of producing confusing error messages when you make a mistake.

String does have an overload for appending a `char`, which is what you perhaps intended. You can convert the integer from the expression back to a `char`:

```
char('A' + i)
```

---

P.S. It is not guaranteed by C++ standard that `'A' + 2` would represent `'C'`. That is a property of the character encoding, and not necessarily the case for all character encodings.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about the final note of the question?

Comment: @Basj that is a completely different question and should be asked in a different post. I don't know much about windows specifics.

Comment: `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[i]` to have the guaranty to have `'C'` with `i == 2`.

Comment: @Jarod42: and it also has the property of missing a letter in case you type it wrong, and no compiler will warn you :-) `'A'`+i = i-th letter is pretty much guaranteed nowadays, the only platforms where this did not hold were IBM dinosaurs using EBCDIC, and hopefully 99% of us can ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

> But what is the natural way to format a std::string with C++?

Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int i = 2;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "hello letter " << char('A' + i) << " bye bye";
std::string s = oss.str();
```

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, is owstringstream the wstring equivalent?

Comment: @Basj close, it is actually `std::wostringstream` instead.